# ng-model="query" not working after connecting to Firebase

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, firebase

Part of a project I am working on is listing members, members companies, etc...  I used $http within my controller to connect to a JSON file to get everything wired up and test functionality. I am using ng-repeat to populate the page and ng-scope to allow visitors to search the listings.

Everything worked as expected until I wired up Firebase to hold the data.  Again, the data populates the page, but now my ng-model is broke and there's no way to search the listings.  My Angular skills are still being polished, to say the least, so I'm sure I am having a noob moment.  Any chance someone could take a look, I 'de be very grateful.  Here is my code.

**My Controller**

```
.controller( 'AlliedCtrl', function AlliedCtrl( $scope, $firebase) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://mybase.firebaseio.com/members");
    var sync = $firebase(ref);
    var syncObject = sync.$asObject();
    syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "members");
});
```

**My HTML**

```
<div class="search-sort">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <input ng-model="query" placeholder="Search and Sort by Keyword e.g. Accounting, Law, Mobile etc..." class="small">
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <table class="table table-condensed table-responsive">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Member Company</th>
                    <th>Company Description</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="m in members | filter:query">
                    <td style="width:250px"></td>
                    <td style="width:250px"><b>{{ m.company }}</b><br>{{ m.address }}<br>{{ m.address2 }}<br><a href="{{ m.url }}" target="_blank">{{ m.url }}</a><br><br>{{ m.name }}<br><em>{{ m.title }}</em><br>{{ m.phone }}<br><a mailto="{{ m.email }}">{{ m.email }}</a><br><br></td>
                    <td>{{ m.description }}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `ng-repeat` on a collection from Firebase, you have to call `$asArray` and not `$asObject` + `$bindTo`.

So in your controller:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://mybase.firebaseio.com/members");
var sync = $firebase(ref);
var syncObject = sync.$asArray();
$scope.members = syncObject;
```

Comment: Bloody marvellous!!  Thank you.  Works like a charm.

@tommyd456 - Thank you for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: To clarify, it's fine to use objects with ng-repeat (e.g. `ng-repeat="(key,val) in object"`), but they will not work with filters or have guaranteed ordering, which is where the array becomes necessary.

Comment: An ng-repeat like that, would be like a "for each (propertyName, propertyValue) in object", right? So useful if you don't know which properties there are, but not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to wait until the `syncObject` has loaded so...

```
//Controller
var members = syncObject.$loaded().then(function() {
  members.$bindTo($scope, "members");
}
```